# HTML5 clean canvas with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, html5-canvas

I have this javascript code, and when i click on the buttons, the canvas cleans.

But when i move the mouse, the canvas shows me what i wrote before, and it doesn't start with a blank canvas

What can i do to start with a blank canvas after i click on the buttons?

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <div id="buttons">
      <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
      <input type="button"  onClick="erase()" value="Erase">
  </div>



  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }

      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', 
                              function(evt){
                                  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
                                  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                                  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
                                  ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
                                  ctx.stroke();
                              }

      );

      document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }, false);


     function erase(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);     
     }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in the **developer** tools console? i.e. about `context` being undefined?

Comment: yes :D Distractions...I've notice and correct my question now. Thank you :) But now i have another question: When i move the mouse, the canvas shows what i wrote before, and doesn't start with blank canvas. How can i do to start with a blank canvas after that I click the buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to use `beginPath()` to also clear the path which stills exists after `clearRect()` has been used, e.g.:

```
function(evt){
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

  ctx.beginPath();     // <- here
  //ctx.moveTo(x, y);  // you will probably also want this at some point

  ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```